# I need to change the Message Order on Ploneboard

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm running Ploneboard 3.2 on Plone 4.2.4 and need to change the order of messages so that the most recent message appears first in the list. I have only limited Plone and Zope experience so your consideration is appreciated! Can this be achieved simply by configuration or is it workflow related?

Comment: Without knowing details: a quick look in the source code brings up a template called "ploneboard_recent.pt" - Maybe this is what you want. You can quickly try it by appending "ploneboard_recent" to your url by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response - What I was hoping to do was re-order the messages within a thread so that the latest message appears first in the thread? "Ploneboard_recent" produces a list of recent messages outside of their thread structure?

Comment: I don't use ploneboard, but maybe this is solvable using a collection?

Comment: If there is no setting around (check the control panel) then workflow is not a solution either, you will have to either customize the template that shows the messages or the python code that feeds that template